# Using Macrovariable in a Date Variable (SAS)

Tags: sas

I am programming in SAS and I am trying to figure out how to use a macrovariable within a date variable;

an example would be something like

```
%let year = 2015;
data test;
set;
date = '01JAN&year.'d;
run;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes and format the variable using the date9. format:

```
%let year = 2015;
data test;
    format date date9.;
    date = "01JAN&year."d;
run;
```